# cross coverage of transition in functional coverage of system verilog

Tags: code-coverage, system-verilog

Is this possible to do cross coverage of transition?
Something like :

```
//A to B is one bin.
//B to C other bin.
```

I want to do cross of this, that is: A to B to B to C

In other words, I have 3 values A,B,C, and I want to check all combinations of transition between A,B,C.

Comment: You seem to be a bit confused about the terminology. You don't cross bins, you cross coverpoints. What I for one understand from your question is that you have only one coverpoint. Please expand on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need cross-coverage to do what you want. Simple transition coverage should be sufficient. You just have to say that you're interested in 2 transitions.

Let's say you have an `enum` type defined like this:

```
typedef enum { A, B, C } some_type_t;
```

You can define double transition for a field of this type as follows:

```
class some_class;
  some_type_t field;

  covergroup cg;
    coverpoint field {
      bins trans[] = (A,B,C=>A,B,C=>A,B,C); 
    }
  endgroup // cg

  function new();
    cg = new();
  endfunction
endclass // some_class
```

This will define a bin for each transition.

Comment: yes this will work.but I have to give all combination.
is there a way to do cross of all combination?

Comment: @user3481828 Don't really get what you mean. Do you mean not having to specify `A,B,C`?

Comment: yes i have 3 values of 1 variable.
now i want to check all transition of variable between 3 values.